# How do I use the IAM role assigned to an ec2 instance with boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to run a python script on an EC2 instance that is meant to upload files to s3. I have created an IAM role that has full permissions to access and alter that S3 bucket. If I run an aws cli command on the ec2 instance, it works fine, for example:

```sh
$ aws s3 ls my-bucket
2020-03-03 11:00:46       4100 myfile.json
```

But, when I try to use boto3 to write to the bucket, it fails:

```py
session = boto3.session.Session()
s3_client = session.client('s3')
s3_client.upload_file(path, 'my-bucket', 'myfile.json')
```

I get this error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

How do I tell boto3 to use the EC2 instance's IAM profile, which should give it permission?

Comment: Are this error ocurring from inside the EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes, this error happens on the EC2 instance.

Comment: Share you role (without sensitive information) so we can review and help you. It seems that your role give you read permission but not write permission. Also make sure your bucket allows you to write on it.

Comment: It is likely that you are successfully attaching the IAM Role to the Amazon EC2 instance, and boto is likely using that role. Thus, the error would be related to the fact that you are attempting to Put an object into an S3 bucket but the IAM Role does not have sufficient permission to do so. You will need to show us the IAM Role and tell us why you think the role is correct.

Comment: By the way, you do not need to create the `Session()`. You could just use: `s3_client = boto3.client('s3')`

Comment: I am actually having this exact same issue. I can list all the objects from the AWS CLI, but cannot simply use @JohnRotenstein's suggestion. My role has read-write access, but I can't even list the buckets.

Comment: @blacktj If you use boto3 to call [`get_user()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_user) and also use the AWS CLI to call [`aws iam get-user`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-user.html), they return the same results?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes... are you going to tell me that it's just a permissions issue then?

Comment: @blacktj You can take a look in AWS CloudTrail to see which specific API call was denied. It might be due to the upload process also setting the `ACL`, which needs `PutObjectAcl` permission.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm actually not even able to list the buckets.. does that require PutObjectAcl permissions?

Comment: @blacktj I suggest you create a new Question with your full details, rather than trying to solve this for you on an old question that does not match your circumstances.